# Where do I output to file

Tags: powershell, automation

Where do I put my line in this code to output to file?  I want it to build it as it is processing the emails but I can't discern where this is taking place.

Honestly, I can't figure out what the output line syntax should be either. Something like this (IDK):

```
$Email | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, bodysubstring | Format-Table -Auto | out-file c:\results.txt
```

Here is the code in its entirety.  I am trying to write my email basic information to a text file that I can examine when traveling.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
#connect to outlook
$GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"; 
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(‘playdude@playboy.com’)
$olxEmailFolder.Name
$olxEmailItem = $olxemailFolder.items

#show unread emails in inbox
$olxEmailItem | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, @{n='bodysubstring';e={$_.body.substring(0,100)}} | Format-Table -auto

#go through each subfolder and get name
$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders
ForEach($Folder in $SubFolders)
{
   $Folder.Name
   $SubfolderItem = $Folder.Items
   $EmailCount = 1
#create status bar for each subfolder
   ForEach($Email in $SubfolderItem)
   {
     Do
     {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Checking folder" -status $Folder.Name -PercentComplete ($EmailCount/$Folder.Items.Count*100)
        $EmailCount++
     }
#show unread emails from subfolders
     While($EmailCount -le $Folders.Item.Count)
   }

}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should append `| Out-File "C:\results.txt"` to the line starting with `$olxEmailItem | select SentOn, ...`. I'm not quite sure what it is you're trying to achieve, though.

Comment: Great Answer @AnsgarWiechers !!! Thank you!  Do you know the MailItem Object for the Folder that the message is in?  Is it olFolderInbox?

Comment: `$olxEmailFolder` is the user's default folder. I'd guess that'd be the inbox.